# kendoUI , How to have onclick function work on kendoPanelBar

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, kendo-ui

I'm trying to have kendoPanelBar implemented. So far it is working good, but I want a click event to work in my kendoPanelBar.

I mean that when I click on the submenu, it should perform some function.

I tried it like this :

```
{
     text: "Search",
     items: [
         { text: "Winning Prize Bond", url: "#", click:onClick },
         { text: "User" }
     ]
},
```

But the onclick function is not working. I even tried select.

Please see my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Wu8MS/6/.

Answer (score 0):

There are no separate item events in Kendo UI PanelBar. You can bind to the select event PanelBar has and it will pass you the selected item along. Check the documentation about it:

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/panelbar#events-select